# Is there a way to increse the speed of the loop or a faster way to do the same thing without using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe (4 million rows and 25 columns). I am trying to investigate 2 categorical columns. One of them has around 5000 levels (app_id) and the other has 50 levels (app_category).

I have seen that for for each level in app_id there is a unique value of app_category. How do I code to prove that?

I have tried something like this:

```
app_id_unique = list(train['app_id'].unique())

for unique in app_id_unique:
    train.loc[train['app_id'] == unique].app_category.nunique()
```

This code takes forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
train.groupby('app_id').app_category.nunique()
```